# How to create a custom NiFi Controller Service?

Tags: apache, minify, apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform, hortonworks-dataflow

I am trying to learn, how to create a custom NiFi controller service. To start off, I thought of mimicking the `DBCPConnectionPool` controller service by simply copying the original source code of `DBCPConnectionPool` service. To implement the same, I generated a maven archetype from "nifi-**service**-bundle-archetype" and got the following project structure
[image]

However, when i generated the archetype from 'nifi-**processor**-bundle-archetype , I got the following structure: -
[image]

I understand that in case of processor I simply need to write my code in `MyProceesor.java` present under `nifi-ListDbTableDemo-processors` folder and then create a nar file out of it. But in case of controller service, I have 4 folders generated. I can see two java files i.e.

1. `StandardMyService.java` present under `nifi-DbcpServiceDemo` folder
2. `MyService.java` present under `nifi-DbcpServiceDemo-api`folder

Now, why is there two java files generated in case of custom controller service, while there was only one java file generated in case of custom processor. Also, Since I am trying to mimick the `DBCPConnectionPool` service, in which java file out of two should I copy the original source code of `DBCPConnectionPool` service.

**Please guide me from scratch, the steps that I need to follow to create a custom service equivalent to that of `DBCPConnectionPool` service.**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`MyService.java` under `nifi-DbcpServiceDemo-api` is an interface which be implemented by the `StandardMyService.java` under `nifi-DbcpServiceDemo`. Once the implementation is done, you have to use `nifi-DbcpServiceDemo-api` as dependency in the processor bundle which needs to work with this custom controller Service.

The reason why controller services are implemented this way is:

- We will be hiding the actual implementation from the processor bundle because it need not depend on the implementation.
- Tomorrow you write a new controller service implementation, say `StandardMyServiceTwo` which again implements `MyService` because only the implementation varies from `StandardMyService` and other members remains the same and can be shared. This new controller service can be introduced transparently without making any changes on the processor bundle.

**Example:**

The best example is the record reader/writer controller services. If you look at the [nifi-record-serialization-services-bundle](https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-record-serialization-services-bundle) in nifi, they have different implementation for serializing records of JSON, Grok, avro, CSV data formats but they all are actually implementing one API - [nifi-record-serialization-service-api](https://github.com/apache/nifi/tree/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-standard-services/nifi-record-serialization-service-api) And hence for the processors which want to use the `Record Reader` or `Record Writer`, instead of having the actual implementations as its dependency, they rather can have the api as its dependency.

So tomorrow you can add add a new implementation in the record-serialization-services-bundle for a new data format without touching anything on the processors bundle.

For you references, please take a look at the following links which would help you in writing the custom controller service from scratch

- http://www.nifi.rocks/developing-a-custom-apache-nifi-controller-service/
- https://github.com/bbende/nifi-dependency-example

Comment: I am getting an error. **The import org.apache.nifi.expression.ExpressionLanguageScope;** cannot be resolved. I already tried using this dependeny https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-expression-language/1.5.0  but the error is not resolved

Comment: `ExpressionLanguageScope` is actually in in `master`. It won't be available in NiFi 1.6.0 or previous libraries. Which version are you using as dependency?

Comment: <version>1.5.0</version>